# Fixed-length string as value type for use in MemoryMappedViewAccessor

Tags: c#, .net, string, types

I would like to store a struct into a MemoryMappedFile, but this struct contains strings (with a max size which I know) that are reference type and therefore rejected by the MemoryMappedViewAccessor.

Do you know a good fixed-length string struct (value type) implementation? I can hard code the length if that is necessary (as arrays are reference types).

For example, I could instantiate it as:

```
TenCharsString myString = new TenCharsString("1234567890");
```

Decorating with the MarshalAs attribute

```
<MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=128)>
```

should work, but it does not.

Comment: MemoryMappedFiles do not use marshalling like P/Invoke. They copy the bytes directly between managed memory and the file.

Comment: What is the exception being thrown? What does the struct look like?

Comment: MemoryMappedViewAccessor only accepts value types, including structs provided they contain only value types (no reference types such as strings).

My struct contains datetimeoffset?, decimal?, long?, and two string fields which cause problems (although their length is fixed in the database for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple 10-character value type:

```
struct TenChars
{
    public char A;
    public char B;
    public char C;
    public char D;
    public char E;
    public char F;
    public char G;
    public char H;
    public char I;
    public char J;
}
```

If unsafe code is an option, this works as well:

```
unsafe struct TenChars
{
    public fixed char Chars[10];
}
```

---

Full code:

```
struct TenChars1
{
    public const int Capacity = 10;

    private char A;
    private char B;
    private char C;
    private char D;
    private char E;
    private char F;
    private char G;
    private char H;
    private char I;
    private char J;

    public TenChars1(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        if (value.Length > Capacity) throw new ArgumentException();

        A = (value.Length > 0) ? value[0] : '\0';
        B = (value.Length > 1) ? value[1] : '\0';
        C = (value.Length > 2) ? value[2] : '\0';
        D = (value.Length > 3) ? value[3] : '\0';
        E = (value.Length > 4) ? value[4] : '\0';
        F = (value.Length > 5) ? value[5] : '\0';
        G = (value.Length > 6) ? value[6] : '\0';
        H = (value.Length > 7) ? value[7] : '\0';
        I = (value.Length > 8) ? value[8] : '\0';
        J = (value.Length > 9) ? value[9] : '\0';
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return new string(new char[] { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J });
    }
}

unsafe struct TenChars2
{
    public const int Capacity = 10;

    private fixed char buffer[Capacity];

    public TenChars2(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        if (value.Length > Capacity) throw new ArgumentException();

        fixed (char* ptr = this.buffer)
        fixed (char* chars = value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                *(ptr + i) = *(chars + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        fixed (char* ptr = this.buffer)
        {
            return new string(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Which implementation do you think would be faster? And what kind of risk is there to use the unsafe version (bad memory management?)?

Comment: Speed shouldn't be much different for this low number of characters. Use a profiler if speed is critical. Unsafe code escapes the safe boundaries of managed code and can be dangerous. If you're not comfortable with dealing with unsafe code, I recommend you go for the safe implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the struct internals individually. You can store the strings as arrays of chars using [WriteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267754.aspx) and [ReadArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267761.aspx). The others can use the various [Write methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor_methods.aspx).